# Upgraded users to Win7. Now getting "path not found" when saving files or opening attachments

Tags: windows-7, permissions, user-profile

We have a Server 2008 AD environment with about 5k users. We just rolled out Windows 7 SP1 (were XP) with great success. However, about once a day we get a few calls that a user opens a file from their Documents (the folder is on the server and redirected), edits it and attempts to save but Win7 reports that the path is not found either because it doesn't exist or no permissions. The only way to fix it is to delete the profile.

In addition we get about the same number but different users saying that they cannot open attachments from Outlook 2010 due to no permission. We have to edit the temp Outlook storage path in the registry to fix it (or delete the profile).

I think the two issues may be related.

What scares us is that we rolled out 1 month ago and had no calls of this nature until about 2 weeks ago. It started off as one or two but seems to be growing.

Any ideas?  We're going to open a Microsoft ticket but I wanted to seenif anyone else has run into this.

Thanks!

Comment: First step would be to try and figure out where it's trying to redirect to. Sysinternals can probably help you there if it's not clear.

Comment: What was the result of the Microsoft ticket?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience.  I know you mentioned the only change being the introduction of win 7, but I'd check beyond just that.  In a previous job, our team had a number of servers in a cluster acting as file shares.  These contained DFS and other folders that were targets from redirection.  When one of the servers had a NIC issue, we used the downtime to update drivers.  This was a bad idea, because the driver update had changed default settings and turned on TOE in the NIC Teaming settings.  TOE or TCP Offload Engine usually optimizes Network by several techniques.  One of these was remembering network routes that had changed.  All of a sudden we had users calling with similar issues to this one... Not much though, only a few a day.  When we finally tracked the problem down, simplying turning off TOE solved it for us.

Edit: forgot to add that I'd need proof to be convinced both those issues are related.

Answer (score 0):

Is the folder where the files are stored in the user's Home folder?  If so, deleting and then reapplying the path to their Home folder in their user account will reset the permissions for all files in the Home folder and these issues will go away.